# Slide feito usando html e css não preenche a largura da página

Tags: html, css, front-end

Estou tentando preencher a tela com os slidEs,porém não consigo. Estou usando o gallery.css para a criação dos slides,tentei modificar no css,porém, o nome da classe que é usado para que o gallery funcione,não permite que eu consiga usar ela no css e modifique o tamanho do slide

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="caixa">
            <h1><img src="img/icone.jpg"></h1>
            <h1><img id="gato" src="img/icone2.jpg"></h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="tratamentos.html">Tratamentos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="consultas.html">Consultas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="higienizacao.html">Higienizaçao</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contatos.html">Contatos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sobrenos.html">Sobre Nós</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="gallery autoplay items-3">
            <div id="item-1" class="control-operator"></div>
            <div id="item-2" class="control-operator"></div>
            <div id="item-3" class="control-operator"></div>

            <figure class="item">
                <h1><img src="img/fachada.jpg"></h1>
            </figure>
            <figure class="item">
                <h1><img src="img/cão.jpg"></h1>
            </figure>
            <figure class="item">
                <h1><img src="img/gato.jpg"></h1>
            </figure>

            <div class="controls">
                <a href="#item-1" class="control-button">.</a>
                <a href="#item-2" class="control-button">.</a>
                <a href="#item-3" class="control-button">.</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Css do gallery.min

```
.gallery .control-operator:target~.controls .control-button{color:#ccc;color:rgba(255,255,255,.4)}.gallery .control-button:first-of-type,.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(1):target~.controls .control-button:nth-of-type(1),.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(2):target~.controls .control-button:nth-of-type(2),.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(3):target~.controls .control-button:nth-of-type(3),.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(4):target~.controls .control-button:nth-of-type(4),.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(5):target~.controls .control-button:nth-of-type(5){color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,.8)}.gallery .item:first-of-type{position:static;pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .item{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;pointer-events:none;opacity:0;transition:opacity .5s}.gallery .control-operator{display:none}.gallery .control-operator:target~.item{pointer-events:none;opacity:0;animation:none}.gallery .control-operator:target~.controls .control-button{animation:none}@keyframes controlAnimation-2{0%{color:#ccc;color:rgba(255,255,255,.4)}14.3%,50%{color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,.8)}64.3%,100%{color:#ccc;color:rgba(255,255,255,.4)}}@keyframes galleryAnimation-2{0%{opacity:0}14.3%,50%{opacity:1}64.3%,100%{opacity:0}}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(1):target~.item:nth-of-type(1){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(2):target~.item:nth-of-type(2){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.items-2.autoplay .control-button{animation:controlAnimation-2 14s infinite}.items-2.autoplay .item{animation:galleryAnimation-2 14s infinite}.items-2 .control-button:nth-of-type(1),.items-2 .item:nth-of-type(1){animation-delay:-2s}.items-2 .control-button:nth-of-type(2),.items-2 .item:nth-of-type(2){animation-delay:5s}@keyframes controlAnimation-3{0%{color:#ccc;color:rgba(255,255,255,.4)}9.5%,33.3%{color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,.8)}42.9%,100%{color:#ccc;color:rgba(255,255,255,.4)}}@keyframes galleryAnimation-3{0%{opacity:0}9.5%,33.3%{opacity:1}42.9%,100%{opacity:0}}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(1):target~.item:nth-of-type(1){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(2):target~.item:nth-of-type(2){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(3):target~.item:nth-of-type(3){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.items-3.autoplay .control-button{animation:controlAnimation-3 21s infinite}.items-3.autoplay .item{animation:galleryAnimation-3 21s infinite}.items-3 .control-button:nth-of-type(1),.items-3 .item:nth-of-type(1){animation-delay:-2s}.items-3 .control-button:nth-of-type(2),.items-3 .item:nth-of-type(2){animation-delay:5s}.items-3 .control-button:nth-of-type(3),.items-3 .item:nth-of-type(3){animation-delay:12s}@keyframes controlAnimation-4{0%{color:#ccc;color:rgba(255,255,255,.4)}7.1%,25%{color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,.8)}32.1%,100%{color:#ccc;color:rgba(255,255,255,.4)}}@keyframes galleryAnimation-4{0%{opacity:0}7.1%,25%{opacity:1}32.1%,100%{opacity:0}}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(1):target~.item:nth-of-type(1){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(2):target~.item:nth-of-type(2){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(3):target~.item:nth-of-type(3){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(4):target~.item:nth-of-type(4){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.items-4.autoplay .control-button{animation:controlAnimation-4 28s infinite}.items-4.autoplay .item{animation:galleryAnimation-4 28s infinite}.items-4 .control-button:nth-of-type(1),.items-4 .item:nth-of-type(1){animation-delay:-2s}.items-4 .control-button:nth-of-type(2),.items-4 .item:nth-of-type(2){animation-delay:5s}.items-4 .control-button:nth-of-type(3),.items-4 .item:nth-of-type(3){animation-delay:12s}.items-4 .control-button:nth-of-type(4),.items-4 .item:nth-of-type(4){animation-delay:19s}@keyframes controlAnimation-5{0%{color:#ccc;color:rgba(255,255,255,.4)}5.7%,20%{color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,.8)}25.7%,100%{color:#ccc;color:rgba(255,255,255,.4)}}@keyframes galleryAnimation-5{0%{opacity:0}5.7%,20%{opacity:1}25.7%,100%{opacity:0}}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(1):target~.item:nth-of-type(1){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(2):target~.item:nth-of-type(2){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(3):target~.item:nth-of-type(3){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(4):target~.item:nth-of-type(4){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.gallery .control-operator:nth-of-type(5):target~.item:nth-of-type(5){pointer-events:auto;opacity:1}.items-5.autoplay .control-button{animation:controlAnimation-5 35s infinite}.items-5.autoplay .item{animation:galleryAnimation-5 35s infinite}.items-5 .control-button:nth-of-type(1),.items-5 .item:nth-of-type(1){animation-delay:-2s}.items-5 .control-button:nth-of-type(2),.items-5 .item:nth-of-type(2){animation-delay:5s}.items-5 .control-button:nth-of-type(3),.items-5 .item:nth-of-type(3){animation-delay:12s}.items-5 .control-button:nth-of-type(4),.items-5 .item:nth-of-type(4){animation-delay:19s}.items-5 .control-button:nth-of-type(5),.items-5 .item:nth-of-type(5){animation-delay:26s}
```

Css do gallery.theme.css

```
.gallery .control-button {
  color: #ccc;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.gallery .control-button:hover {
  color: white;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

/*
    Theme controls how everything looks in Gallery CSS.
*/
.gallery {
  position: relative;
}
.gallery .item {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4d87e2;
}
.gallery .controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.gallery .control-button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .02em;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .1s;
}
```

A exibição fica da seguinte maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

As classes `.gallery .item` no seu css possuem uma altura já definida de 400px e aparentemente ele está mantendo a proporção da imagem.

Se você quer realmente forçar o aumento da imagem sugiro deixar essas classes da seguinte forma:

```
.gallery .item {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4d87e2;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Aqui você encontra todas as propriedades de `img` e `figure`: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_images.asp

Espero ter ajudado.